# How to create a subscription which generates a report for last business day of the month

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

In reporting service (SSRS), I am trying to automate the process which produce the reports for the last working business day of the month. I want to create a subscription which gives me this result. I can see the options which allows me to generate the reports every Friday of the week or Any day of the last week but I cannot see the options which can let me generate the subscription for the last business day of the month. I would really appreciate if someone can guide me how do I resolve this problem.

Comment: have you had a look at this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlrnnr/2017/05/22/ssrs-custom-shared-schedule/

Comment: It was helpful. Thank you.